# Rails nested circular dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with circular dependencies:

```
class InventoryItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :bin

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bin
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bins
  has_many :inventory_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bins
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bins
  has_many :inventory_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bins
end
```

[image]

The `inventory item` form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :location do |location| %>
      <%= location.label :location_name %>
      <%= location.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :bin do |bin| %>
      <%= bin.label :bin_name %>
      <%= bin.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And the `inventory item` controller:

```
  def new
    @inventory_item = InventoryItem.new
    @inventory_item.build_bin
    @inventory_item.build_location
  end

  def inventory_item_params
    params.require(:inventory_item).permit(:location_id, :bin_id, location_attributes:[:name], bin_attributes:[:name])
  end
```

But when I submit the form I had the error:

```
Bin location must exist
```

I don't know where or how to create the relation between `Bin` and `Location` or if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have circular dependencies.

- Location relies on nothing to be created
- Bin relies on location
- InventoryItem relies on bin and location

So if you create them in the right order

1. Location
2. Bin (attached to location)
3. Inventory Item (attached to both)

you should be fine.

Something like this

```rb
# the nesting in params may be off but you can definitely figure this out by looking at the console log of form's request.

    # 1. Create location with name (no dependencies)
    location = Location.create({name: params[:location][:name]})

    # 2. Create bin referencing location
    bin = Bin.create({location: location, name: params[:bin][:name]}) 
  
    # 3. Create inventory item referencing both.
    @inventory_item = InventoryItem.create({bin: bin, location: location})
```

I'm not sure how to do this with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but that would be a clean solution if you can get it working.